# Role Object Pattern implementation in Solidity

Tags: design-patterns, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I am implementing Role Object Pattern in solidity. My implementation looks like this.

```
interface IEmployee{
    function getName() external  view returns (string memory);
    function getAge() external  view returns (uint256);
    function addRole(address account, EmployeeRole abc) external;

  }

contract EmployeeCore is IEmployee {
    string name;
    uint age;
    mapping(address => EmployeeRole)  role;

    constructor  (string memory name1,uint age1) {
     name = name1;
     age = age1;
    }


    function getName() public  virtual override view returns (string memory){
        return name;

    }
    function getAge() public  virtual override view returns (uint256){
        return age;
    }

    function addRole(address account, EmployeeRole er) public virtual override {
        role[account] = er;
    }

}

abstract contract EmployeeRole is IEmployee{

    EmployeeCore core;
    function getName()  override public view  returns (string memory){
    return core.getName();
    }

    function getAge() override public view  returns (uint256){
    return core.getAge();
    }


    function addRole(address account, EmployeeRole er) public override{
        core.addRole(account,er);
   }
}

contract Manager is EmployeeRole{
    function manageInventory() pure  public returns (string memory){
        
        string memory job = "Manage Inventory";
        return job;
    }

    
}

contract Supplier is EmployeeRole{
    function manageSupplies() public pure  returns (string memory){
        string memory job = "Manage Supplies";
        return job;
    }

    
}
```

Now in another contract I instantiate my classes and assign roles like this:

```
    IEmployee emp1 = new EmployeeCore("Samuel", 21);
     Manager m1= new Manager();
     emp1.addRole(address("0XJJJJJ"),m1);

     m1.getAge();
     m1.getName();
```

I am getting the following error on the last 2 i.e m1.getName(), m1.getAge() :

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit  (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas"

AND

error: ProviderError: execution reverted

I think my execution of transaction on the last two function calls is getting rejected as somehow I am not correctly accessing these functions. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "0XJJJJJ" isn't a valid address.

Comment: I have added this address for questions sake. I am adding correct metamask address in the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, it is about the wrong address of a contract with non-payable function. For instance, the following code snippet is working:

```
    //SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.7;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

interface IEmployee{
    function getName() external payable returns (string memory);
    function getAge() external  payable returns (uint256);
    function addRole(address account, EmployeeRole abc) external;

  }

contract EmployeeCore is IEmployee {
    string name;
    uint age;
    mapping(address => EmployeeRole)  role;

    constructor  (string memory name1,uint age1) {
     name = name1;
     age = age1;
    }

    function getConractAddressEmployeeCore() public view returns(address){
        return address(this);
    }


    function getName() public  virtual override payable returns (string memory){
        return name;

    }
    function getAge() public  virtual override payable returns (uint256){
        return age;
    }

    function addRole(address account, EmployeeRole er) public virtual override {
        role[account] = er;
        console.log("account of the EmployeeCore role", account);

    }

}

abstract contract EmployeeRole is IEmployee{

    EmployeeCore core;
    function getName()  override public payable  returns (string memory){
    return core.getName();
    }

    function getAge() override public payable  returns (uint256){
    return core.getAge();
    }


    function addRole(address account, EmployeeRole er) public override{
        core.addRole(account,er);
        console.log("account of the EmployeeRole role", account);
    }

    function getContractAddressEmployeeRole() public view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }
}

contract Manager is EmployeeRole{
    function manageInventory() pure  public returns (string memory){
        
        string memory job = "Manage Inventory";
        return job;
    }

    function getContractAddressManager() public view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }


    
}

contract Supplier is EmployeeRole{
    function manageSupplies() public pure  returns (string memory){
        string memory job = "Manage Supplies";
        return job;
    }

    
}

contract Test {
    function testFunction() public {
    IEmployee emp1 = new EmployeeCore("Samuel", 21);
    Manager m1= new Manager();
    console.log("manage inventory logging", m1.manageInventory());
    emp1.addRole(m1.getContractAddressManager(), m1);
    m1.getAge();
    //m1.getName();
    }
}
```

You can deploy the Test contract and call the testFunction() method.